# Camptune is stuck on “Resizing volumes, this may take a while...” for the past 6 hours

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, dual-boot

I’m trying to increase the partition on my Windows partition and decrease the size of the MacOS Catalina partition by 18 GB on my 256 GB, 2014 dual-booted MacBook Air using Paragon Camptune, a third-party software. It’s been stuck on “Resizing volumes, this may take a while...” for the past 6 hours.

I’ve submitted a support ticket with the maker of the software, Paragon, and still haven’t heard back. They did say they respond to tickets in 1-3 business days. I also Dm’ed them on Twitter. I can’t cancel the resizing process, because then I’ll lose my data, so it doesn’t allow that.

If you’ve used Camptune to resize your partitions, how long does it usually take? Do I just let it do its thing in the meantime? I’d hate to have it leave it on plugged in overnight. [image: Screenshot of my MacBook]

Comment: Judging by timestamps; it was 6PM 8 hours ago so now 2AM Thurs…I'd give it another 6 hours & see where it's got ;) Tasks like this wil be highly dependant on how big the drive is [small] & how full it is [unknown].

Comment: @Tetsujin I just woke up. I still have the same screenshot. What do I do?

Comment: If you have full backups, you can risk force-quitting the task or hard rebooting & see what happens - restore if it all goes badly wrong [which is highly likely]. If you don't, you're going to have to weigh patience against risk. I'd give Paragon a shout, see what they say.

Comment: @Tetsujin I paid $108 for their highest tier technical support. Going to see what they say today

Comment: Still haven’t heard back. It’s been stuck like this for 25 hours now! I just want this torture to end!!

Comment: I'm afraid you're at the point where patience must be balanced against the length of time since your last complete backup of both OSes. btw, it's 'easter weekend' & the middle of the biggest lockdown since WWII… so I wouldn't expect responses to be particularly rapid.

Comment: I’m this close to force quitting the program and destroying my Mac.

Comment: If you have good backups - just blow it out of the water… who cares. You can rebuild the whole thing in an hour.

Comment: @Tetsujin how do I do that?

Comment: Do which? Blow it out of the water? Reboot to Internet Recovery, erase the drive & reinstall the OS, then migrate in your Time Machine. Then either set up a fresh Boot Camp & migrate that backup, or, depending on your backup format, just image it back to a new partition.